# SVN - Release branch and bug fixes

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

Lets say we have release branch called "v1.0". The work in trunk continues (developing future versions - v1.1). Now I detect a critical BUG in the v1.0 which has to be fixed NOW. After fixing the bug in the release branch, it still exists in trunk. How do I fix the same bug in trunk I have fixed in the release branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pull just those changes to the trunk is to create a patch for the revision that fixed the bug (using diff) and apply that to the trunk.

I just found a great explanation of how to do the above here:
http://bro-ids.org/wiki/index.php/Subversion#How_to_merge_features_into_the_trunk_.28Vern-style_:-.29

(This year, we've been working with hg where it's much easier.)

Comment: I am fixing the bug in the release branch, tagging from this branch and merging tag to trunk with reintegrate. Is this a valid scenario (it works pefrecly - or maybe I don't know something about reintegration)?

Comment: Of course I am not right. When I try to do it with another release I am getting a lot of conflicts because TAG wants to add all previous versions again. Still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 5):

You need to merge the branch back in to the trunk.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html